# Mono Develop - how to switch to design view

Tags: .net, monodevelop

I just got started with Mono Develop and Im trying to make a simple application,but I cant figure out how to get into deisgn view insted of code view.

I'm using windows 7 & MonoDevelop 2.6 RC1

Comment: Isn't MonoDevelop for .NET?  Nothing to do with VBA...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the GUI, you need to open the MainWindow.cs file, which creates a new tab in the editor window and loads the file for editing, clicking after that on "Designer view".

Regards

Comment: The Source view and Design view is under the bottom of the editing window.

Comment: I have Xamarin 5.10. In my ASP project, I see Source tab at the bottom, but  do not see Design tab. I have both the .asp and .cs files open.

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm a little late to the party, but I thought I'd add this here in case someone else has this same problem.

To get to the Designer tab again, close ALL tabs in Mono and then double-click MainWindow.cs. You should now see the Design tab again. Hope this helps somebody!